# Why cant I access a variable outside a Capistrano task

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have want to set this deferred variable in Capistrano which depends on some variable I set during calling the task

```
set(:installation_dir) do 
    if target == "staging"
        "/some/path"
    else
        "/some/other/path"
    end
end

task :foo do
    p "INSTALLATION_DIR >>> #{installation_dir}"
end
```

If running the task this error happens

```
Hector:monitoring-agent robertj$ cap foo -s target=development
/Users/robertj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@pf/gems/capistrano-2.15.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:122:in 
`method_missing_with_variables': undefined local variable or method `target' for 
#<Capistrano::Configuration:0x007fd6a22f9100> (NameError)
```

This is making me mad. Why doesnt Capistrano 2.x have a simple way to access variables where ever I call.

Comment: I have found an work around by accessing "self.logger.instance_variable_get('@options')" but this is really ugly and depends on deep structural knowledge of Capistrano::Configuration and its referenced objects

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, `fetch` do what you want

```
p "INSTALLATION_DIR >>> #{fetch(:installation_dir)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run it like that, you're setting an environment variable. To use it in your Capistrano script you need to `set :target, ENV['target']`.

Comment: Hi Marco, sadly not. ENV doesnt contain "-s varname=varvalue". I could read it out of the ARGV array and parse it on my own #facepalm. What is really annoying me is that I can see the value. its somehow for unknown purposes stored in the logger object of the configuration. But cant access it. I only see it when I inspect the configuration object

Comment: Hm yeah I kind of missed the `-s`. Without it my idea should work though. :) Also, have you experimented `-s` vs `-S`?

Comment: without -s all params will be interpreted as additional task to be executed. i think